# P4V Clear the drop-down menu in the tree view for workspaces

Tags: drop-down-menu, perforce, p4v

In P4V (Perforce visual client) there is a tree view, where you can browse your files. In the top of that view, there is a dropdown menu, where you can select the workspace you want to browse through.
[image: Screenshot of drop-down menu]

I have just deleted a whole bunch of old workspaces, but they still show up in the drop-down menu. I cannot find any place to get rid of them.

I will be happy to know how to either:

1. remove specific workspaces from the drop-down, or
2. remove all workspaces from the drop-down

Answer (score 2):

I used P4V Rev. Perforce Visual Client/MACOSX106X86_64/2014.1/827578 and had 10 workspaces listed in the drop down.  As I deleted them they were removed from the drop-down.  What version of P4V are you using?

Comment: I am using Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2014.1/888424. Downloaded it just a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

I am using P4V (on Windows 7), dated **2013 March 20** and versioned:

```
Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2013.1/611291
```

My problem was somewhat different than that described in the question. A number of my old workspaces were showing up in the P4V workspace drop-down menu, even though these old workspaces no longer existed on the server. (I did not delete those workspaces; I'm guessing they were deleted by an admin.)

In my case, I found a way to remove these orphaned names from the workspace drop-down menu. **Here's what I did:** For each workspace name in the drop-down menu I wanted to remove, I:

1. Recreated a workspace with the identical name. (I found that the root folder that I assigned to the workspace did not matter.)
2. Immediately deleted the workspace.
3. This resulted in the workspace name being automatically removed from the workspace drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have P4V Rev. P4V/NTX64/2023.2/2467475

In the bottom of the drop down list there is an option 'Edit Recent Workspaces...', press on it and un-check in the window that will appear all workspaces you want to remove from it.